# Coding for a collision

Tags: python

My code represents a basketball being shot into a hoop.  Now I want it to print "Brick" whenever the ball hits the rim and "Swish" when it goes straight through without touchin the rim.  I am having some trouble getting it to work though.

```
import math as m
from vpython import *
import numpy as np

ground = box(pos=vector(0,0,0), 
size=vector(10,0.2,1),color=color.green)
ball = sphere(pos=vector(-4.8,2,0), radius=.25, 
color=color.orange)
rim = ring(pos=vector(0,3,0), axis=vector(0,.1,0), 
radius=.45, thickness=.01, color=color.white)

g = vector(0,-9.8,0)
v0 = 6.0
theta = 60*pi/180

ball.m = .625 #kg
ball.v = vector(v0*cos(theta),v0*sin(theta),0)

t = 0
dt = 0.01

attach_trail(ball)

while ball.pos.y>=0:
    rate(100)
    F=ball.m*g
    ball.v=ball.v+(F/ball.m)*dt
    ball.pos=ball.pos+ball.v*dt/ball.m
    t=t+dt
    dr = ball.pos - rim.pos
    mdr = m.sqrt(dr.x**2 + dr.y**2 + 
    dr.z**2)
    if mdr <= ball.radius:
        print("Brick")
```

I tried getting the difference between the ball position and the rim position and seeing if that magnitude was less then the ball radius but I guess I wasn't setting it up right because it was not working for me.

Comment: Can you explain "trouble getting it to work" in more technical detail? Do you have any unit tests for this code?

Comment: sorry, its for a school project so I kind just started with the language.  But what I tried was taking the ball.pos - rim.pos. and seeing if the magnitude of that value was <= to the ball radius in the while loop.  But I wasn't getting any results.  I just need it to print "Brick" when the ball hits the rim.

Comment: Your code doesn't print anything. Where did you expect something to be printed? Have tried using the `print()` function?

Comment: yes i have sorry i had that originally in my code. I took it out when I went back to refresh and get my simulation working again.  What I wanted was when the ball passed through the rim it would print Brick, or when it went through the hoop it would print Swish but instead it would just pass through and nothing would print when either case happened.

Comment: It doesn't print anything because there is no `print()` in the code. Show how you have tried to use `print()`, otherwise we can't tell you what might have been wrong.

Comment: Ok i just editted it to what I tried, but as you can see the simulation doesn't run now.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see if the simulation runs or not. I'm not sure why what you have just added should make it not run if it did run before.

Comment: Ok, sorry, in the original code the ball goes through its projectile motion like its supposed to but now it does not move.

Comment: Sidenote: if `F = ball.m * g` and `ball.v = ball.v + (F / ball.m) * dt` then what you really wrote is `ball.v = ball.v + g * dt` using too many letters. Also note that if you're constantly updating the position of the ball, you need to recompute `dr` and `mdr` at every new position.

Comment: so do they both need to be in the while loop?

Comment: of course: if you update the position of the ball, the distance between the ball and the rim changes, so every time you update the ball, you need to also update that distance measure.

Comment: ok I move them to the loop but I am still not getting a print.  Does my math make sense or am i thinking about it wrong?

Comment: Unrelated: using standard code formatting/conventions will make your code easier for others to read and understand. For example: put spaces before and after most arithmetic operators, don't split a line into two lines unless it's too long (50 is not too long), don't start variable names with an uppercase letter (use `f` or `force` instead of `F`). If your IDE has an autoformat button/keycombo, you should probably use it regularly.

Comment: Sorry, like I said this is for a class. I didn't know about any of that but I'll try.